# How do I colour the table?

Tags: tkinter, colors, python-3.4

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

height = 8
width = 8
for c in range(height): #Rows
    for d in range(width): #Columns
        b = Entry(root, text="")
        b.grid(row=c, column=d)

mainloop()
```

I have created a table in Python using *tkinter* but as part of my project I need the cells to be separate colours. I need each individual cell to be a separate colour from the rest and I am a bit stuck because usually I use *HTML* but my task is in python.

Does anyone have any ideas in how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()

height = 8
width = 8

for r in range(height):
    for c in range(width):
        colour = "#%06x" % random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF)
        b = Entry(root, text = '', bg = colour)
        b.grid(row = r, column = c)

mainloop()
```